# Why Android Activity gives black screen after 3 weeks of working 24/7?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview

**Edit:**

I have found out that the screen goes off even after the weekend. It has to do something with **inactivity**, because if the tablet has been used or touched, the time without the screen going off is longer.

It is not dark, the screen is just turned off. But I only have to touch it 3 times and it goes back on to the first app activity.

**Original post:**

I have developed a simple kiosk app for Android using Kotlin, which is basically a kiosk web browser. It consists of 2 Activities:

- **MainActivity**, where the user puts URL address of a website
- **WebViewActivity**, which loads the URL address, forces full screen and also makes it able to turn on the kiosk mode by tapping 7 times in top left corner of the screen

The application needs device owner rights in order to use the kiosk functions.

Tablets with this app were working quite fine for almost a month. They have power supply, so the tablets are working **24/7** with the screen always on and **WebViewActivity** displaying a web app.

Last week I have noticed one of them has gone into **black screen** - I though the power was off but all I had to do was to touch the screen multiple times - it brought back the **MainActivity** and made it possible to load URL again. On Tuesday it happened again on 4 more devices, and today it happened on one of them.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    var url : String
    val editText: EditText = findViewById(R.id.editText)
    val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)

    val pref1 = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val text = pref1.getString("URL", "")
    editText.setText(text)

    button.setOnClickListener {
        url = editText.text.toString()

        if (Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(url).matches() && url.startsWith("http")){
            val pref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            val editor = pref.edit()

            editor.putString("URL", url)
            editor.apply()

            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, WebViewActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("url", url)
            startActivity(intent)
        }else{
            editText.text.clear()
            editText.hint = "Please insert correct url address!"
        }
    }
}
```

}

**WebViewActivity.kt**

```
class WebViewActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private var currentApiVersion: Int = 0
private var mDpm: DevicePolicyManager? = null
private var mIsKioskEnabled: Boolean = false

private var count = 0
private var startMillis: Long = 0

private var password = "****"
private var typedPassword: String? = null

private val displaymetrics = DisplayMetrics()

private var checker = false

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview)

    val deviceAdmin = ComponentName(this, AdminReceiver::class.java)
    mDpm = getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE) as DevicePolicyManager
    if (!mDpm!!.isAdminActive(deviceAdmin)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.not_device_admin), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    if (mDpm!!.isDeviceOwnerApp(packageName)) {
        mDpm!!.setLockTaskPackages(deviceAdmin, arrayOf(packageName))
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.not_device_owner), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
    val url = intent.getStringExtra("url")

    val myWebView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webview)
    myWebView.webViewClient = CustomWebviewClient()
    myWebView.clearCache(true)
    myWebView.clearHistory()
    myWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    myWebView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true;
    if (url != null) {
        myWebView.loadUrl(url)
    }else{
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com")
    }

    currentApiVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
    val flags: Int = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
    if (currentApiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = flags
        val decorView: View = window.decorView
        decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener { visibility ->
            if (visibility and View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN === 0) {
                decorView.systemUiVisibility = flags
            }
        }
    }
}

inner class CustomWebviewClient : WebViewClient() {
    val url = intent.getStringExtra("url")
    override fun onReceivedError(view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest, error: WebResourceError) {
        super.onReceivedError(view, request, error)

        if(error.description == "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"){
            if(!checker){
                checker = true
            }else{
                checker = false
                Handler().postDelayed({
                    if (url != null) {
                        view.loadUrl(url)
                    }
                }, 150000)
            }
        }else{
            if (url != null) {
                view.loadUrl(url)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onReceivedHttpError(view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest, errorResponse: WebResourceResponse) {
        super.onReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse)
        if (url != null) {
            view.loadUrl(url)
        }
    }
}

override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
    if (currentApiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && hasFocus) {
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
    }
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (!mIsKioskEnabled){
        finish()
    }
}
```

I have modified Web View a little, so it makes auto-reload when facing an error except the one that the Web App is throwing all the time.

I am pretty new to Android development and Kotlin, this is actually my first app. Could the problem be caused by the lack of **OnResume()** and putting all of the code in **OnCreate()**? I do not understand why by tapping the screen couple of times, it goes back to **MainActivity**. Or could it be some memory overload, because the app is running for so long?

I would be glad for any help, as I could not find any solution and the problem is quite hard to reproduce.

Comment: The use case of running an Activity for weeks/months is such a corner case I think you're going to have a hard time getting a good answer.  A weekly reboot may be appropriate.  OnCreate vs onResume won't matter unless you have something that needs to be redone, but honestly you'd be more likely to see issues from switching between activities or apps than just having a static screen.

Comment: What type of blank screen did you get-  was the screen off or was it a bright black (actively displaying black)?  Did the tablet go into a power saving mode of some sort?Does the webapp make requests to the server, and if so is there a case where it may output a blank page (perhaps in the case of a timeout or a login token expiring)?

Comment: If you ran out of memory, I think the app would simply crash, not go to a black screen. The fact that it comes back after tapping the screen makes me think this is possibly some quirk with Android itself after running that long with the screen on, and not necessarily with your app specifically.

Comment: Tbh I am not sure, but the screen was not off, so it must have been displaying black color. All of the power saving options are turned off. I was thinking the problems might be caused by the web app, not kiosk app, but in this case it should not go back to the MainActivity after taping the screen couple of times.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I couldn't find what was causing the problem, but looks like adding a scheduled activity restart every 12 hours solved the issue. I added this piece of code in OnCreate of WebView Activity.

```
 val timer = Timer()
    val timerTask: TimerTask = object : TimerTask() {
        override fun run() {
            val time = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
            val midnight = "19:00:00"
            val morning = "07:00:00"
            if (time == midnight){
                finish()
                startActivity(intent)
            }else if (time == morning){
                finish()
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    }
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 1)
```